# Purpose of `numpy.log1p( )`?

Tags: python, numpy

I just came across one of these [Kernels](https://www.kaggle.com/yadavsarthak/you-got-this-feature-engineering-and-lasso) and couldn't understand what does `numpy.log1p()` do in the third pipeline of this code (House Prediction dataset in Kaggle).

Numpy documentation said

*Returns*:
  - An array with natural logarithmic value of x + 1
  - where x belongs to all elements of input array.

What is the purpose of finding log with one added while finding skewness of original and transformed array of same features? What does it actually do?

Comment: because log of zero produces an error...

Comment: We are never giving zero to log because `feat_trial` has data in it . Btw my question was what's the point of taking log actually?

Comment: OK I got it logs are used to respond to skewness towards large values; i.e., cases in which one or a few points are much larger than the bulk of the data. but why add 1 to x; while it is not even empty and has data in it?

Comment: log1p is also useful for summing log probabilities (a common representation for probabilities). More details at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Log_probability

Answer (score 73, accepted):

The [NumPy docs give a hint](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.log1p.html):

> For real-valued input, `log1p` is accurate also for `x` so small that `1 + x == 1` in floating-point accuracy.

So for example let's add a tiny non-zero number and `1.0`. Rounding errors make it a `1.0`.

```
>>> 1e-100 == 0.0
False
>>> 1e-100 + 1.0 == 1.0
True
```

If we try to take the `log` of that incorrect sum, we get an incorrect result (compare to [WolframAlpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=ln(1+%2B+1e-100))):

```
>>> np.log(1e-100 + 1)
0.0
```

But if we use `log1p()`, we get the correct result

```
>>> np.log1p(1e-100)
1e-100
```

The same principle holds for [`exp1m()`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.expm1.html) and [`logaddexp()`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.logaddexp.html): The're more accurate for small `x`.

Comment: Thanks, also clear if this only applies for small values of x? 
Since the input we're giving to this np.log1p() , i.e. 'feat_trial` has large values in it

Comment: Their precision is expected to be good for all numbers (all float numbers lose precision for large values though)

Answer (score 12):

[image: https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.log1p.html]

[image]

If x is in range 0...+Inf then it will never cause an error (as we know log(0) would cause an error).

Not always the best choice, because as you see you will lose a big curve before x = 0 that is one of the best things about log function

Comment: I don't see how that is the reason log1p is useful (as opposed to just using log(1 + x)). If we are assuming x is in [0; +inf], then avoiding a log(0) error would not be a reason for the existence of log1p(x) because log(1 + p) would never raise that error.

Answer (score 1):

When your input value is so small, using `np.log1p` or `np.expm1` to calculate, you will get the more accutrate result than `np.log` or `np.exp` according to the interpretation from [this link](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.log1p.html).

Answer (score 1):

It is also used to normalize distributions.
Some distributions are log-normal, and this function will help to normalize the data you're working with.

```
data["Log1pSalary"] = np.log1p(data["SalaryNormalized"]).astype("float32")

 plt.figure(figsize=[8, 4])
 plt.subplot(1, 2, 1)
 plt.hist(data["SalaryNormalized"], bins=20)

 plt.subplot(1, 2, 2)
 plt.hist(data["Log1pSalary"], bins=20)

 plt.show()
```

[image]